# Skype - getting rid off cross-signing keys

Tags: apt, package-management, gnupg, keyrings

With a fresh Ubuntu 23.04 installation, I would like to manage all keys in a proper way and get rid off the cross-siging threat.

I've installed Skype simply by:

```
wget -c https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Unfortunatelly, I've discovered (in `apt-key list`) that Skype key was stored in a common file `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`.

So, I've downloaded Skype key once again, but to a separate file, **but not in `/usr/share/keyrings/`**

```
curl -sS https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/skype.gpg
```

**And my Question #1 is: Do I have to update the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list` to something like:**

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/skype.gpg] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
```

**I'm asking this, because Chrome installation created a separate key file `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-chrome.gpg`, however in corresponding source list file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`, there's no *singed-by* option:**

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

It seems Chrome is working fine without this option and I'm a little bit confused.

**Question #2: What is the most suitable location for the separate key files?**

- `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`
- `/usr/share/keyrings/`
- `/etc/apt/keyrings/`

What are the nuances between these three locations?